# Floating label animation lag while using it in a scroll view

Tags: android, android-textinputlayout

I have layout with the floating text label / text input layout. While adding a scrollview to the layout the floating label animation lags in a lower end (Moto G) device. The animation works fine without the scroll view. below is my layout

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    tools:context=".activities.LoginActivity"
    >

    <include
        android:id="@+id/branding_text"
        layout="@layout/branding_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
        />

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/loginLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:cardElevation="4dp"
        app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
        tools:visibility="visible"
        >


        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="16dp"
            >

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                style="@style/TextAppearance.ClinicalKey.FloatLabel"
                >

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/edit_username"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:hint="@string/account_username_hint"
                    android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                    android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
                    android:nextFocusDown="@+id/edit_password"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    />

            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>t>

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                style="@style/TextAppearance.ClinicalKey.FloatLabel"
                >

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/edit_password"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:hint="@string/account_password_hint"
                    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                    android:imeActionId="@+id/action_sign_in"
                    android:inputType="textPassword"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    />

            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                >

                <Button
                    style="?android:borderlessButtonStyle"
                    android:id="@+id/btRegister"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="end"
                    android:text="@string/register"
                    android:textColor="@color/accent"
                    />

                <Button
                    style="?android:borderlessButtonStyle"
                    android:id="@+id/btLogin"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/login"
                    android:textColor="@color/primary"
                    />

            </LinearLayout>


            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btForgotPassword"
                style="?android:borderlessButtonStyle"
                android:textColor="?attr/colorAccent"
                android:text="@string/reset_password"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                />


        </LinearLayout>


    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <com.lsjwzh.widget.materialloadingprogressbar.CircleProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
        style="@style/CenterProgressBarStyle"
        tools:visibility="gone"
        />

</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: what's you animation code ? anim xml ?

Comment: I dont have my own animation , I am using the design library

Comment: does it lag while adding scrollview only  or always from this ?

Comment: just when I add the scrollview

Comment: can't you add the scrollview before the animation ?

Comment: Any solution to this?

Comment: Please see my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34992839/edittext-in-textinputlayout-lagging/56812693#56812693