# EditText in TextInputLayout lagging

Tags: android, performance, animation, android-edittext, android-textinputlayout

I have two views using `TextInputLayout`. The first one is a login view which has only 2 input fields and the second one is a register view which has many input fields. I am using `TextInputLayout` and `EditText`/`AppCompatEditText` with custom themes for my inputs.
The problem is, when i click on my `EditText`'s in my Register screen i get a kind of lag/spikes on the default `TextInputLayout` animation. I don't get the lag in my `LoginScreen` but the code I'm using is quite the same, so i suppose the problem is in the number of inputs. Any idea or thoughts?
Here is my register code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".activities.MainActivity">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:title="Register as shipper"
    app:titleTextColor="@color/white" />

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="@dimen/space">

        <View
            android:layout_width="0px"
            android:layout_height="0px"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColorHint="@color/hintTextOnLightBackgrounds"
            app:hintTextAppearance="@style/TextLabel">

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
                android:id="@+id/fullNameEdit"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:hint="@string/shipper_register_full_name"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:nextFocusLeft="@id/fullNameEdit"
                android:nextFocusUp="@id/fullNameEdit"
                android:theme="@style/EditText" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColorHint="@color/hintTextOnLightBackgrounds"
            app:hintTextAppearance="@style/TextLabel">

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
                android:id="@+id/companyNameEdit"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:hint="@string/shipper_register_company_name"
                android:theme="@style/EditText" />

        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColorHint="@color/hintTextOnLightBackgrounds"
            app:hintTextAppearance="@style/TextLabel">

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
                android:id="@+id/phoneNumberEdit"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:hint="@string/shipper_register_phone_number"
                android:theme="@style/EditText"
                android:inputType="phone" />

        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColorHint="@color/hintTextOnLightBackgrounds"
            app:hintTextAppearance="@style/TextLabel">

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
                android:id="@+id/emailEdit"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:hint="@string/shipper_register_email"
                android:theme="@style/EditText"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />

        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColorHint="@color/hintTextOnLightBackgrounds"
            app:hintTextAppearance="@style/TextLabel">

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
                android:id="@+id/passwordEdit"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:hint="@string/shipper_register_password"
                android:theme="@style/EditText"
                android:inputType="textPassword" />

        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColorHint="@color/hintTextOnLightBackgrounds"
            app:hintTextAppearance="@style/TextLabel">

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
                android:id="@+id/addressEdit"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:hint="@string/shipper_register_address"
                android:theme="@style/EditText"
                android:inputType="text" />

        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner
            android:id="@+id/typeSpinner"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/registerBtn"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/space"
            android:text="@string/shipper_register_register"
            android:theme="@style/ButtonPrimary" />

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

and the login:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="@dimen/space">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
    android:src="@drawable/logo_color"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<View
    android:layout_width="0px"
    android:layout_height="0px"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true" />

<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColorHint="@color/hintTextOnLightBackgrounds"
    app:hintTextAppearance="@style/TextLabel">

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
        android:id="@+id/emailEdit"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/login_email"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:theme="@style/EditText" />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColorHint="@color/hintTextOnLightBackgrounds"
    app:hintTextAppearance="@style/TextLabel">

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
        android:id="@+id/passwordEdit"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:hint="@string/login_password"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:theme="@style/EditText" />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/loginBtn"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/login_login"
    android:theme="@style/ButtonPrimary" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/shipperRegisterBtn"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/login_register_as_shipper"
    android:theme="@style/ButtonPrimary" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/carrierRegisterBtn"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/login_register_as_carrier"
    android:theme="@style/ButtonPrimary" />
```

Comment: have you found any solution, cause i have a same problem right now, its working fine in 21 or below.. but in marshmellow its lagging too much.. even scrolling also lagging.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the reason for the lag is that the hint animation of TextInputLayout and the adjustment made to the activity's main window happening at the same time (because of showing soft keyboard).

In my case using `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"` inside the activity tag in Manifest does the job, because it makes keyboard appear over the content without any adjustment made to the activity's main window, however it is up to you to decide if keyboard can overlay your TextInputLayout.

As the last option we can set `app:hintAnimationEnabled="false"` to the TextInputLayout.